# How to achieve the equivalent of WNetAddConnection2 with a timeout?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, networking

The following call to WNetAddConnection2 seems to hang forever. Note that the machine name is intentionally wrong - I'd like this to fail fast rather than block forever. Is there a way to achieve similar functionality but with a timeout?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public class NETRESOURCE
        {
            public int dwScope;
            public int dwType;
            public int dwDisplayType;
            public int dwUsage;
            public string LocalName;
            public string RemoteName;
            public string Comment;
            public string Provider;
        }
        [DllImport("mpr.dll")]
        public static extern int WNetAddConnection2(NETRESOURCE netResource, string password, string username, int flags);

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NETRESOURCE myResource = new NETRESOURCE();
            myResource.dwScope = 0;
            myResource.dwType = 0; //RESOURCETYPE_ANY
            myResource.dwDisplayType = 0;
            myResource.LocalName = "";
            myResource.RemoteName = @"\\invalid.machine.com";
            myResource.dwUsage = 0;
            myResource.Comment = "";
            myResource.Provider = "";

            int returnValue = WNetAddConnection2(myResource, "password", "username", 0); //hangs forever
            Debug.Print("Finished connecting");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Forever is a long time. How long did you wait? It should eventually timeout.

Comment: Several minutes :) I'd rather have my thread wait for seconds.

Comment: Put it in a thread and setup a WaitHandle (like `ManualResetEvent`) with a timeout on the `WaitOne` and then (do the dirty way) terminate the thread using `Thread.Abort`.

Comment: If Thread.Abort is anything like TerminateThread then I'd rather avoid it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa450930.aspx "TerminateThread is a dangerous function. Use it only in the most extreme cases."

Comment: @M.Babcock: `Thread.Abort` is unnecessary because it can't abort the connection attempt anyway.

Answer (score 3):

On earlier versions of Windows it was impossible to terminate a process that was stuck in one of the WNetAddConnection functions.  This was fixed in Vista.  [According to Larry Osterman](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2006/04/19/579174.aspx), the fix is the [CancelSynchronousIo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363794%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

The solution to your problem is:

1. Start a new thread to run WNetAddConnection2
2. Set a timer or wait in your existing thread.
3. After the timeout call CancelSynchronousIo specifying the handle of the connection thread.

I can't think of any reason why this would interact badly with .Net, but I haven't actually tried it...

Comment: +1 for the answer, but this raises the question, "How do you get the native thread handle of a managed thread, and should you even do that when native threads have no fixed relationship to a managed thread?"

Comment: You could pinvoke to GetCurrentThreadId just before calling WNetAddConnection2, though this isn't 100% reliable (your managed thread could get rescheduled on a different native thread between the two calls).  You could write an unmanaged DLL that launched WNetAddConnection on a new thread and returned the thread ID.  Though that's a bit scruffy.

Comment: I tried this but got ERROR_NOT_FOUND, even though the thread was blocked on WNetAddConnection2. According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363794%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, "If this function cannot find a request to cancel, the return value is 0 (zero), and GetLastError returns ERROR_NOT_FOUND."

Comment: I can't make it work either.  I've asked a question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475581/does-cancelsynchronousio-work-with-wnetaddconnection2

Comment: @Jon: It looks like my suggestion was balls: CancelSynchronousIo doesn't seem to work with WNetAddConnection2.  You could use a separate process, which could safely be killed.  Or you could just leave the connection attempt running in a separate thread and forget about it.

Comment: Thanks for trying. I was hoping for an alternative API which is either asynchronous or offers a timeout, but I guess maybe there isn't one.