# Does CancelSynchronousIo work with WNetAddConnection2?

Tags: windows, winapi, networking

I'm trying and failing to cancel a call to [WNetAddConnection2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385413%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with [CancelSynchronousIo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363794%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The call to CancelSynchronousIo succeeds but nothing is actually cancelled.

I'm using a 32-bit console app running on Windows 7 x64.

Has anyone done this successfully?  Am I doing something dumb?  Here's a sample console app (which needs to be linked with mpr.lib):

```
DWORD WINAPI ConnectThread(LPVOID param)
{
    NETRESOURCE nr;
    memset(&nr, 0, sizeof(nr));
    nr.dwType = RESOURCETYPE_ANY;
    nr.lpRemoteName = L"\\\\8.8.8.8\\bog";

    // result is ERROR_BAD_NETPATH (i.e. the call isn't cancelled)
    DWORD result = WNetAddConnection2(&nr, L"pass", L"user", CONNECT_TEMPORARY);

    return 0;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    // Create a new thread to run WNetAddConnection2
    HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(0, 0, ConnectThread, 0, 0, 0);
    if (!hThread)
        return 1;

    // Retry the cancel until it fails; keep track of how often
    int count = 0;
    BOOL ok;
    do
    {
        // Sleep to give the thread a chance to start
        Sleep(1000);
        ok = CancelSynchronousIo(hThread);
        ++count;
    }
    while (ok);

    // count will equal two here (i.e. one successful cancellation and
    // one failed cancellation)

    // err is ERROR_NOT_FOUND (i.e. nothing to cancel) which makes
    // sense for the second call
    DWORD err = GetLastError();

    // Wait for the thread to finish; this takes ages (i.e. the
    // WNetAddConnection2 call is not cancelled)
    WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It cancels I/O operations, driver IRPs.  WNetAddConnection2 is a very different animal.

Comment: If I do a FindFirstFile on a remote server then the first thing it does is block trying to initiate a connection, presumably using exactly the same internal code and IRPs as WNetAddConnection2.  There doesn't seem to be any fundamental difference, yet the former is cancellable and the latter apparently isn't.  Am I missing something?

Comment: (You forgot to say @Hans.)  I'd hazard a guess that in the case of a FindFirstFile to a UNC path only the FindFirstFile operation itself is cancelled, the network connection attempt itself might well be completed (or timed out) and then discarded.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: When networked I/O is really slow it's almost always because the remote server is down and Windows has a long timeout waiting for a response that will never come.  Especially in this example where I'm connecting to a non-existent server; the connection attempt is the only thing that FindFirstFile is doing.  And it's definitely getting cancelled.

Comment: @arx: how do you know?  Have you checked what's happening at the network layer?  (My point is that just because FindFirstFile has returned doesn't necessarily mean that Windows isn't still trying to make the connection.)  But perhaps the connection attempt is being successfully cancelled in that case, and it's just that WNetAddConnection2 isn't associating the relevant IO request with the calling thread in the same way file operations do ... I'm not sure it matters.  Whatever the reason, if it doesn't work, it doesn't work.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Maybe Windows is still trying to make the connection, but FindFirstFile somehow escaped from the synchronous call it made, so there's no reason WNetAddConnection2 can't either.  But as you say, if it doesn't work the reasons are academic.

Comment: @arx: just guessing, but there may be design issues related to support for third-party network providers.  The WNetAddConnection functions are implemented by user-mode code in a network provider DLL (NPAddConnection) so any IRPs are probably issued from a system thread within the MPR rather than from your thread.  No doubt it would be possible to make this work one way or another but I'm guessing MS never even thought of it.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378775%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Pragmatic suggestion: since network connections are per-session, you could issue the call to WNetAddConnection2 from a subprocess if that would help.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: I'd already thought of using another process, but I wondered if it could be made to work in-process.  I guess not.  Cheers anyway.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: And I guess you're right about the difficulty being third-party network providers.  Though do any exist now?

Comment: No idea, but AFAIK the MS network providers are implemented the same way.

Comment: It seems that when running "net use" from cmd.exe, it spawns net.exe which blocks on WNetAddConnection2. When pressing Ctrl-C, net.exe is killed, presumably by cmd.exe. Is my understanding of this correct?

Comment: @Jon.  Yes.  If you do a "dir" in cmd.exe then it runs in-process and exits with a different error message when you press Ctrl+C: ("The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Larry Osterman (I hope he doesn't mind me quoting him): "The question was answered in the comments: wnetaddconnection2 isn’t a simple IOCTL call." So the answer (unfortunately) is no.

Comment: Cheers, though I'm curious.  Is Larry a mate of yours?

Answer (score 0):

First, `WNetAddConnection2` is system-wide, not per-process. This is important, as calling `WNetAddConnection2` many times can wreck system stability - particularly with explorer.

I use `WNetGetResourceInformation` first to check if the connection already exists before even thinking of calling it - my process may have previously run and then shutdown. The connection may still exist. When my Windows service(s) needs to add such a connection I use a nasty little trick in order to prevent these totally non-abortable API's from stalling my own service shutdown.

The trick is to run these calls in a separate process: they are system-wide, after all. You can normally wait for the process to complete as if you called the functions yourself but you can terminate the process and give up waiting if you need to abort in order to shutdown.

Sadly, however, certain Windows resources, such as named pipe handles and handles to files open on remote computers, can take about 16 seconds to close following failure or shutdown of a remote machine. `CancelSynchronousIo` does not seem to even help with those but will likely add additional long delay.